# PostgreSQL Failed to startup

Tags: centos, postgresql, database

I am having trouble with starting PostgreSQL on my CentOS system. Here are my error logs below. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
2017-04-25 03:18:12.553 CDT > LOG:  could not bind IPv6 socket: Address already in use

2017-04-25 03:18:12.553 CDT > HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.

2017-04-25 03:18:12.553 CDT > WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "*"

2017-04-25 03:18:12.553 CDT > FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets

2017-04-25 03:18:12.554 CDT > LOG:  database system is shut down
```

Comment: Perhaps you have another server (e.g. another PostGresql daemon) using the same port

Comment: I dont to my knowledge. Postgres was working fine but didn't seem to start again once I had stopped the service. How would I check that there is not another service using the same port?

Comment: Error seems explicit : **HINT: Is another postmaster already running on port 5432?**

Answer (score 1):

You're probably running another service using port 5432. To verify try doing `ss -lnpt` (use sudo in case you're not root). You'll be able to see which process is using TCP port 5432 if this is the case.

Comment: Or use [netstat(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/netstat.8.html) to check the same

Comment: When I ran this command I got this output for that port. Not sure how to chnage it so that I can get Postgres to start. 

LISTEN     0      128                      :::5432                    :::*      users:(("postmaster",11717,4))
LISTEN     0      128                       *:5432                     *:*

Comment: @Grant please edit your question to add requested information, comment are hard to read.

Comment: @Grant As you can see some process with PID 11717 is using TCP port 5432. Now it depends on your intent. If you're shure that port 5432 shouldn't be used, go ahead and stop the service. If you don't know what is to be stopped, kill the process with `kill 11717` or `kill -9 11717` if first command doesn't do the job. But **it may lead to service interruption for particular process you're trying to kill**.